# Nested for loop pattern in C

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

i want to know whats the best way to understanding a pattern and start using nested for loops to draw out patterns in C.

Example :

+++++

++++

+++

++

+

Comment: You don't need a nested loop for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's that homework about pyramids..

Comment: Be careful as the word *pattern* might have [other meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) in computer science not related to what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define the pattern creation in steps.
In your example, this pattern creation would need 5 steps, one for each line.
Then, you need to figure out what happens in each step.
Again, in your example, you need to write 5 plus signs at step 0, 4 plus signs at step 1, etc.
Therefore, if you formalize what to do in each step, for example as a function of the currect step, you can just loop over the steps and create your pattern.